# Let $f(x)=7-3x$, evaluate and simplify the following $\frac{f(1)}{x}$

Tags: calculus, inverse

Using this equation, how would I be able to simplify this? My initial thoughts are, this would be an inverse function and it would be as follows:

$f(x)=7-3x$

Then, multiply both sides by $-3x+7$, which would be

$-3fx^2+7fx=1$

Then, factoring it out

$f(-3x^2+7x)=1$

Divide both sides by $-3x^2+7x$, like such: $\frac{(-3x^2+7x)}{(-3x^2+7x)}=\frac{1}{-3x^2+7x}$

So, $f=\frac{1}{-3x^2+7x}$

Would I be on the right track here?

Many thanks in advance!

UPDATE - I have a practice question and this was how the directions were written. Apologies for the confusion. I'll try to reword this post.

Comment: You want to simplify $\frac{f(1)}{x}=\frac{4}{x}?$

Comment: $f(1) = 7 - 3(1) = 7 - 3 = 4$.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Do you mean "find the inverse function $f^{-1}(x)"$?

Comment: Every single step you make is nonsensical.

Comment: Sahiba Arora, thank you for your help.
user658409, this wasn't helpful, as I'm learning, it would be helpful next time to provide where I went wrong so I can improve my method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{f(1)}{x}=\frac{7-3}x=\frac4x.$$

There is nothing that you can simplify.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for providing an explanation and your reasoning.